# Filter query with result of aggregate

Tags: sql, django, aggregate-functions

In a Django app, I have four models -- 'Proposal', 'ProposalRevision', 'Opinion', and 'User'.  Here are simplified definitions:

```python
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Proposal(models.Model):
    pass

class ProposalRevision(models.Model):
    proposal = models.ForeignKey(Proposal)
    created = models.DateTimeField()

class Opinion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    proposal = models.ForeignKey(Proposal)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

Each proposal may have many revisions; and a user may have many opinions for a given proposal.  The query I'd like to make is:

> Retrieve all the proposals where a given user has not left an opinion
>   since the last proposal revision was created.

The application use-case is that I want to show the user the proposals that they need to leave an opinion on.

Naively, I thought to do the query this way:

```python
Proposal.objects.annotate(
        latest_revision=Max('proposalrevision__created')
    ).exclude(
        opinion__user=user,
        opinion__created__lte=F('latest_revision')
    )
```

However, this doesn't work because [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) don't work with aggregations ([yet](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030)).

In order to work around this with an "[extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)" query, I started to try to write vanilla SQL that would do the query I wanted, but I got stuck with using the aggregate in the 'where' clause.  The SQL I'm working with looks like this:

```sql
SELECT ...snip..., MAX("proposal_proposalrevision"."created") as "latest_revision"
FROM "proposal_proposal"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "proposal_proposalrevision" ON
    ("proposal_proposal"."id" = "proposal_proposalrevision"."proposal_id")
WHERE "proposal_proposal"."id" NOT IN (
    SELECT (U1."proposal_id") FROM "proposal_opinion" U1
    WHERE (
        U1."user_id" = 1 AND U1."proposal_id" IS NOT NULL AND
        U1."created" > "latest_proposal"
    )
)
GROUP BY ...snip...
```

SQLite gives me the error "`misuse of aggregate: MAX()`".  This holds whether I use the the variable name "`latest_proposal`", or replace it with a repeat of the aggregate function `MAX("proposal_proposalrevision"."created")`.

How else could I build this query to filter the returned set using the aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT a.*, b.maxrevisiondate AS latest_revision
FROM proposal_proposal a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT proposal_id, MAX(created) AS maxrevisiondate
    FROM proposal_proposalrevision
    GROUP BY proposal_id
) b ON a.id = b.proposal_id
LEFT JOIN proposal_opinion c ON
    a.id = c.proposal_id AND
    (b.maxrevisiondate IS NULL OR c.created > b.maxrevisiondate) AND
    c.user_id = <user_id here>
WHERE c.proposal_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick as a raw query.  In order to get this integrating more easily with the ORM, I decided instead to add a post_save signal to the ProposalRevision model, which updated a "is_stale" boolean on all the Opinion models for the Proposal based on their date, simplifying the queries immensely.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE cannot access the result of an aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT title, avg(val) as average
FROM numbers 
WHERE average = 2 -- error
GROUP BY title;
```

For reference, this is the error given by MySQL for the same situation, which perhaps provides more insight:

> Unknown column 'average' in 'where clause'

Back to SQLite, the solution is to either use HAVING instead (if you have a GROUP BY clause), to filter the aggregated groups:

```sql
SELECT title, avg(val) as average
FROM numbers 
GROUP BY title
HAVING average = 2;
```

or use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT title, avg(val) as average
  FROM numbers 
  GROUP BY title
) WHERE average = 2;
```

Example on DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gXN4MWa3Qi1DqZNQLjmNz5/5

---

The way `SELECT` works differs for normal queries, aggregate queries without a GROUP BY, and aggregate queries without a GROUP BY.

(Aggregate queries are those that use GROUP BY (case 3) or an aggregate function like MAX (case 2 or 3).)

SQLite reference:

> - If the SELECT statement is **a non-aggregate query** , then each expression in the result expression list is evaluated for each row in the dataset filtered by the WHERE clause.
> - If the SELECT statement is **an aggregate query without a GROUP BY** clause, […]
> - If the SELECT statement is **an aggregate query with a GROUP BY** clause, then each of the expressions specified as part of the GROUP BY clause is evaluated for each row of the dataset […]. Each row is then assigned to a "group" based on the results; […]
>
>   If a HAVING clause is specified, it is evaluated once for each group of rows as a [boolean expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#booleanexpr). If the result of evaluating the HAVING clause is false, the group is discarded. […]
>
>   […]
>
> --- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset

---

Example data:

```
title,val
a,1
a,2
a,3
b,1
b,2
c,0
c,2
c,4
```